# PHP preg_replace: Need to modify hyperlink text if hyperlink contains 'youtube.com'

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm almost there!

Here is the string I am trying to adjust, and my preg_replace attempt.

`$description_string = '<p>Here is the test link: <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MFn8L9tIrg" target="_blank">“Man or Muppet”</a> with other text afterwards.</p>';`

`$description = preg_replace( '/(<a[^>]+youtube[^>]*>)+[^"]*(<\/a>)+/', '$0Watch This Video$2', $description );`

The result I'm getting is incorrect:

Here is the test link: “Man or Muppet”Watch This Video with other text afterwards.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! THanks!

Comment: Stop using regular expressions, start using `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Agreed with @Jon, this is not a regular expression candidate, you should use document analysis instead...

Comment: Why is DOMDocument better in this case?

Comment: I appreciate the help if I am using a shitty method.
But I've got a deadline and the code is *almost* working, so for now I just need to fix it and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure if you are trying to get the actual title in there. But here is what I came up with:

```
<?php
$description_string = '<p>Here is the test link: <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MFn8L9tIrg" target="_blank">\'Man or Muppet\'</a> with other text afterwards.</p>';

$description = preg_replace( '/(<a[^>]+youtube[^>]*>)+[^"]*(<\/a>)+/', '$1Watch This Video$2', $description_string );

echo $description;
?>
```

Result:

```
<p>Here is the test link: <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MFn8L9tIrg" target="_blank">Watch This Video</a> with other text afterwards.</p>
```

Your biggest issue was with the quotes (") being in the title. It is cutting off the anchor tags. While using $0 is also incorrect. You'll need to use $1.

This may not be exactly what you need, but its a quick monkey patch for you.